# Variables in formula

Tags: excel, vba

I've defined x & Y and both return the required values but the field only populates the formula with text x & Y

I've checked against defining variables and its what I'm doing

```
Sub FindLast()

Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer

x = InStrRev(Range("H2"), ")")
y = 999


Range("I2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(RC[-1],x,y)"
ActiveCell.AutoFill Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).End(xlDown).Offset(0, 1))

End Sub
```

I get the `formula =MID(H2,x,y)`
I Should get `=mid(H2,77,999)`

Answer (score 1):

Anything you put in quotes will appear as written so you need to take the variables outside. Also, you can [remove the Select/ActiveCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C273.0840) bit.

```
Sub FindLast()

Dim x As Integer, y As Integer

x = InStrRev(Range("H2"), ")")
y = 999

Range("I2").FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(RC[-1]," & x & "," & y & ")"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I though the & was just for spaces in text. You learn every day. Tested and works.Thanks SJR.