# How to include variables in Range.Formula in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am tying to replicate an excel formula `IF(A2>300,"PASS","FAIL")` using Range.Formula in VBA, but it is not working as required.

I am trying to call variables into the formula itself as shown below but it is retuing "end of statement" error. Somebody please help! Thanks

```
col_label = "A"
Range("B1").Formula = "=IF(" & col_label & 2" > 300, ""PASS"", ""FAIL"")"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45321109/vba-variable-in-formula and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54400248/variables-in-formula

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA -- variable in .formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45321109/vba-variable-in-formula)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything after col_label should be in quotes (double-quoted where necessary):

```
col_label = "A"
Range("B1").Formula = "=IF(" & col_label & "2 > 300, ""PASS"", ""FAIL"")"
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you - OP is referred to screen shot.